# Compilation error in the Scala/Play example application for Heroku using Intellij

Tags: scala, heroku, intellij-idea, sbt, playback

I am trying to compile the scala/Play framework example application on my local machine, but I am getting compilation errors when trying to compile using the SBT console in IntelliJ:

```
error: scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError: object java.lang.Object in compiler mirror not found.
```

I also got this message in the event log related to different SBT versions:

```
14:48   Started sbt shell with sbt version 0.13.18 instead of 0.13.11 configured by project.
            Update sbt version
            Disable version override
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Which JDK are you using for the project? I guess it is too new. Try to use a Java 8 SDK..

Answer (score 0):

For the first error

> error: scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError: object java.lang.Object in compiler mirror not found.

You might want to try and ensure that you are using a compatible java version. Like @cbley suggested, try making you are using version 8 of the JDK. 
For the second error

> 14:48   Started sbt shell with sbt version 0.13.18 instead of 0.13.11 configured by project.
>               Update sbt version
>               Disable version override

Its just suggesting you update the version of sbt (which is most likely declared in your **build.properties** file in a folder called **project**. You can just search for it by double tapping shift in IntelliJ. But you are safe to ignore it if you cloned some example repository as well.
[check](https://alvinalexander.com/source-code/how-tell-what-version-sbt-project-is-using)